# Failure of of read/write on Linux

Tags: linux, io, linux-kernel

Here is the issue: I have an an sdcard connected to my linux box through a usb. The sdcard has some extra hardware that does some processing of the data you write to a specific file myfile.dat. You get the new data when you do a subsequent read. Here are the parameters I'm using for open:

```
filehandle = open(fileName, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_SYNC | O_DIRECT);
```

My problem is that when I write to this file then read from it the data is same. This is not how it works on Red Hat 5.9 and 6.2. On those linuxes I get back the new data but on Red Hat 4.8 I get back the old data. I would like to have the same behavior as Red Hat 5.9 and 6.2. Thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by "Linux 4.8", et al? The current version of the Linux kernel is 3.10.4.

Comment: sounds interesting. Which sd-card is this?  what extra hardware does it have?...

Comment: @duskwuff Based on the version numbers, sounds like RHEL versions.

Comment: @duskwuff Sorry, I meant to add Redhat next to 4.8, 5.9 and 6.2.

Comment: @TheCodeArtist I can't give too many details about the hardware but you can think of it as a very small microcomputer using the sd as an interface. It's sole mode of operation is writing to this file myfile.dat, grabbing that data, processing it then returning the result to the same myfile.dat

Comment: is there any difference in the mount cmd flags in both the cases?

Comment: A good place to start might be the RHEL5 release notes (or corresponding kernel version release notes) looking for changes in file handling behavior and the like. To help isolate the problem, you might try a small program that writes to a file on a standard hard drive, waits for keyboard input or something while you manually change the file contents, then reads it back in. If that works as expected, the problem is likely somewhere further down the line in the interface to the device.